# Creating a lat/lon grid from lat/lon point data of a given variable in python?

Tags: python, pandas, coordinates, interpolation, geospatial

I have a large dataframe, df, which I have created from multiple files of scattered, irregular data.

The df is very long (8131596) and has the columns: date, latitude, longitude, var1, var2.

I would ideally like to create a 2D grid/map of certain latitude/longitude bounding box, and apply my df so any data that falls within that lat/lon is included. Or, create 2D lat/lon grid from my data and I can cut it later (ie, end up with a 2D 'image' / matrix).

I will then interpolate between these irregular points, ending up with essentially a data field for each of the variables in the df.

However I am a bit stuck with what is the best way to go about this. I think perhaps mesh grid will be involved, but I can't seem to find any previous questions/help that relates this situation.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for var1 you would have to repeat this for var2

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
from rasterio.crs import CRS

# define interpolation inputs
points = list(zip(df.longitude,df.latitude))
values = df.var1.values # change to var2 for second grid

# define raster resolution
rRes = 50

# create coord ranges over the desired raster extension
xRange = np.arange(df.longitude.min(),df.longitude.max()+rRes,rRes)
yRange = np.arange(df.latitude.min(),df.latitude.max()+rRes,rRes)

# create arrays of x,y over the raster extension
gridX,gridY = np.meshgrid(xRange, yRange)

# interpolate over the grid
gridPh = griddata(points, values, (gridX,gridY), method='linear')

# show interpolated values
plt.imshow(gridPh)
plt.colorbar()

# definition of the raster transform array
from rasterio.transform import Affine
transform = Affine.translation(gridX[0][0]-rRes/2, gridY[0][0]-rRes/2)*Affine.scale(rRes,rRes)
transform

# get crs as wkt
# use your crs here
rasterCrs = CRS.from_epsg('32718')
rasterCrs.data

#definition, register and close of interpolated raster
interpRaster = rasterio.open('./interpRaster3.tif',
                                'w',
                                driver='GTiff',
                                height=gridPh.shape[0],
                                width=gridPh.shape[1],
                                count=1,
                                dtype=gridPh.dtype,
                                crs=rasterCrs,
                                transform=transform,
                                )
interpRaster.write(gridPh,1)
interpRaster.close()
```

Comment: Very helpful, especially the #comments, thank you! Makes the lines of code I had seen around previously much clearer. Could you explain (or point me in the direction of a simple explanation) of what the bits after the initial plotting mean? eg interpRaster? Python can't open the variable

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by bits after initial plotting mean?

Comment: For example the line plt.imshow(gridPh)  ;  plt.colorbar()  plots the result. What do the transform and interpRaster results do? I can't open up interpRaster when I click on it in the spyder variable explorer, so not sure what it is that has been generated.

Comment: Oh load it with rasterio and read its first band

Comment: https://geobgu.xyz/py/rasterio.html